# Spark : construct join expression dynamically

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have to join two datasets using a join expression :

```
ds1.join(ds2, joinExpr)
```

`joinExpr` for example can be `ds1.col(price).equals(ds2.price)`

But I have to externalize the join columns dynamically using a external property file :

```
-price
-name
-adress
...
```

Is it possible to construct this expression dynamically ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [expr(String)](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#expr-java.lang.String-) as `joinExpr`. The string parameter can be any valid SQL expression that could be loaded or constructed from a configuration file.

```java
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.*;

//construct test data
df1 = ...
//+---+---+
//|  a|  b|
//+---+---+
//|  1|  2|
//|  3|  4|
//+---+---+

df2 = ...
//+---+---+
//|  c|  d|
//+---+---+
//|  1|  1|
//|  3|  5|
//+---+---+

//define the join condition. It could be loaded from a file
String joinCondition = "a=c and b>d";

df1.join(df2, expr(joinCondition)).show();

//+---+---+---+---+                                                               
//|  a|  b|  c|  d|
//+---+---+---+---+
//|  1|  2|  1|  1|
//+---+---+---+---+
```